# Dispatch action on Angular router change

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm using Ngrx in Angular 8 app, and I want to dispatch an action when user closing the router. What options do I have? Do I have to create the new Guard and implement CanDeactivate method from the router, or I can do it without any additional services, straight from my component? Thanks for any tips or examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using NgRx I suggest listening to the router effects within the module that needs to perform the action.

On that specific router event you can dispatch your action.

Router events: https://angular.io/api/router/Event

Example effect:

```
routerEvents$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.router.events.pipe(
        filter((event) => {
            return event instanceof <event> // replace with your router event
        }),
        mergeMap(() => {
            // do some stuff
        })
    );
});

constructor(
    private router: Router
) {}
```